# Giving the ParentClass parameter to ChildClass without remaking the ChildClass

Tags: flutter, dart

When passing the `parentData` to `ChildFrame`

For example, I do like this.

```
class MainFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  MainFrame({ Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainFrame> createState() => _MainFrameState();
}

class _MainFrameState extends State<MainFrame>{
  var parentData = [];s
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ChildClass(parentData:this.parentData)  
  }
}

class ChildFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  var parentData;
  ChildFrame({ Key? key,this.parentData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChildFrame> createState() => _ChildFrameState();
}

class _ChildFrameState extends State<MainFrame>{
  var parentData = [];
  var childData = [];
  initState(){
    childData = time()
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ... 
  }
}
```

This gives the data to ChildFrame but when parentData is changed,

I need to break and remake the ChildFrame again.

When breaking child class, other variables belonging to  childFrame also broken.

So, I want to give the `parentData` to `ChildClass` without remaking the `ChildClass`.

Is it possible??

Comment: What do you mean with break? When the `parentData` changes you need to rebuild (get the `build` method to be called again by using `setState` or some other mechanism) `ChildFrame` for these changes to be visible.

Comment: I mean `break` is not rebuild, appearance rebuild is ok, but I want the member variable of class to be kept.